# What is the React way of doing Angular's orderBy

Tags: reactjs

What is the React way to do  [orderBy](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_orderby.asp) filtering from Angular?

How would you order the animals by age in this example?

## [CodePen](https://codepen.io/muscaiu/pen/ayOXYd)

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      animals: [
        {id: 1, age: 5, type: "cat"}, 
        {id: 2, age: 3, type: "dog"},
        {id: 3, age: 10, type: "wolf"}
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    let {animals} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {animals.map((animal)=>{
          return (<p key={animal.id}>{animal.type}</p>)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JydzXy?editors=1010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is sort objects while rendering them:

```
  render() {
    let {animals} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
      {[...animals].sort((a,b) => {return a.age - b.age}).map((animal)=>{
        return (<p key={animal.id}>{animal.type}</p>)
      })}
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: You need to `slice` animals first. `sort` sorts items in place! Or use one of the undescore/lodash utility methods. The native `sort` method is not stable therefore calling it in `render` might not be the best idea because it can randomly change the order of items that are equal (have the same age).

Comment: @Sulthan sort sorts in place and also returns sorted array, so slice is not necessary.

Comment: @dfsq That's not the point. The point is that you are changing `state` without calling `setState`.

Comment: I agree with @sulthan changing state in render is bad practice and should not be tolerated. Although slice is a bit outdated:) so we take destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)

Just install it as dependencies

```
npm install --save lodash
```

---

And import it

```
let _ = require('loadash')
```

---

```
  render() {
    let {animals} = this.state;
    let animalsByAge = _.orderBy(animals, 'age')

    return (
      <div>
        {animalsByAge.map((animal)=>{
          return (<p key={animal.id}>{animal.type}</p>)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```